# passport.use is not being called

Tags: express, passport.js

I want to learn how to use passport js, so I created a dummy project with front-end and express back-end, the front-end form is sending a post request to "/emailAndPassword" route on express.
the request is sent successfully but passport.use is not being called and the authenticate middleware is allway redirected to "/failure" route.
Can anybody help me, the code is here:

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const passport = require("passport");
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const session = require("express-session");

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "secret",
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
  })
);

passport.use(
  new LocalStrategy(
    { usernameField: "username", passwordField: "password" },
    function(username, password, done) {
      return done(null, { username: "rest@test.com", password: "some-characters" });
    }
  )
);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("success");
});
app.get("/failure", (req, res) => {
  res.send("failure");
});
app.post(
  "/emailAndPassword",
  passport.authenticate("local", {
    failureRedirect: "/failure",
    successRedirect: "/",
  }),
  (req, res) => {
    res.redirect("/")
  }
);
app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log("listening...");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `passport.use()` function below `passport.initialize()`

Like:

```
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

passport.use(
  new LocalStrategy(
    { usernameField: "username", passwordField: "password" },
    function(username, password, done) {
      return done(null, { username: "rest@test.com", password: "some-characters" });
    }
  )
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working.